# what environment issue cause batch file function not working properly

Tags: batch-file

I have one script and one configure file.
in configure file mainly have

```
SNFold_1="ORKI App 1.0.0.0219"
SNFile_1="8520010008_852001.T3A.pkg"
SNPrm_1="8520010008_852001.P3A.txt"
SNXML_1="852001.xml"  

SNFold_2="iConnect REST Server 1.8.0.0017"
SNFile_2="8296831817_829683.P3A.pkg"
SNPrm_2="8296831817_829683.P3A.txt"
SNXML_2="829683.xml"
```

In the main script file
I have below code:

```
@echo off
  set SNFold_1=%SNFold_1:"=%
  set SNFile_1=%SNFile_1:"=%
  set SNPrm_1=%SNPrm_1:"=%
  set SNXML_1=%SNXML_1:"=%

  set SNFold_2=%SNFold_2:"=%
  set SNFile_2=%SNFile_2:"=%
  set SNPrm_2=%SNPrm_2:"=%
  set SNXML_2=%SNXML_2:"=%

call:signFunc "%SNFold_1%" %SNFile_1% %SNPrm_1% %SNXML_1%
call:signFunc "%SNFold_2%" %SNFile_2% %SNPrm_2% %SNXML_2%

call:end

EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL% 

:signFunc    - here starts Sign function

::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: prepare sign xml file
::::::::::::::::::::::::

cd %NEW_PACKAGE_BASE_PATH%\%NEW_PACKAGE_NAME%\%New_PACK_PTN%\Sign\xml

copy %NEW_PACKAGE_BASE_PATH%\%NEW_PACKAGE_NAME%\%New_PACK_PTN%\Sign\Temp\sample.xml .

Set "search=sign folder"
Set "replace=%~1"
Set "textfile=sample.xml"
Set "newfile=indesnew.txt"
(
    For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr /N "^" "%textfile%"') Do (
        If "%%B"=="" (
            Echo=
        ) Else (
            Set "line=%%B"
            SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            Set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
            Echo=!line!
            EndLocal
        )
    )
)>"%newfile%"
Del "%textfile%"
Ren "%newfile%" "%textfile%"

Set "search=sign binary file"
Set "replace=%~2"
Set "textfile=sample.xml"
Set "newfile=indesnew.txt"
(
    For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr /N "^" "%textfile%"') Do (
        If "%%B"=="" (
            Echo=
        ) Else (
            Set "line=%%B"
            SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            Set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
            Echo=!line!
            EndLocal
        )
    )
)>"%newfile%"
Del "%textfile%"
Ren "%newfile%" "%textfile%"

Set "search=sign parameter"
Set "replace=%~3"
Set "textfile=sample.xml"
Set "newfile=indesnew.txt"
(
    For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr /N "^" "%textfile%"') Do (
        If "%%B"=="" (
            Echo=
        ) Else (
            Set "line=%%B"
            SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            Set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
            Echo=!line!
            EndLocal
        )
    )
)>"%newfile%"
Del "%textfile%"
Ren "%newfile%" "%textfile%"

rename sample.xml %~4

cd "%SignKit_Path%"

call antCmdLine.bat %NEW_PACKAGE_BASE_PATH%\%NEW_PACKAGE_NAME%\%New_PACK_PTN%\Sign\xml\%~4 mockup 

EXIT /B 0

:end
move "%SignKit_Path%\sign_file.log" "%NEW_PACKAGE_BASE_PATH%\%NEW_PACKAGE_NAME%\%New_PACK_PTN%\Sign\Temp"
@RD /S /Q "%NEW_PACKAGE_BASE_PATH%\%NEW_PACKAGE_NAME%\%New_PACK_PTN%\Sign\xml"
```

now the issue was this.
I ran it in my computer it ran smoothly from

- call:signFunc "%SNFold_1%" %SNFile_1% %SNPrm_1% %SNXML_1%

then second

- call:signFunc "%SNFold_2%" %SNFile_2% %SNPrm_2% %SNXML_2%

But when it ran in my colleague computer it came across this issue

- call:signFunc "%SNFold_1%" %SNFile_1% %SNPrm_1% %SNXML_1%

ran fine 
but just after that I got a pause to ask **Press any key to continue...**
After hit any key, then the second loop was running like **@echo on** and even hanging...

Both my colleague and I are using Windows 10

Is any thing different on my colleague's computer cause this happen?

Based upon your input, I just modified two things and make that works easily

- 1) Changed the format of configure file. In this file.cfg, I list
  parameters as below:
- "ORKI App 1.0.0.0219" 8295650401_CAVDEV.P3A.pkg 8295650401_CAVDEV.P3A.jsat 829565.xml
- "iConnect REST Server 1.8.0.0017" 8296831817_829683.P3A.pkg 8296831817_829683.P3A.txt 829683.xml
- 2)Then In the main script file

  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in (file.cfg) do call :signFunc %%A %%B %%C %%D

  :signFunc    - here starts Sign function

And it works OK.

Comment: What about this to remove the quotes: `for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%U in ('set SN') do set "%%U=%%~V"`? And replace `cd` by `cd /D`. Concerning your actual problem: there is not a single `pause` command in the script you posted, so your collegue's version appears to be different than yours...

Comment: antCmdLine.bat may not be the same on both machines

Comment: When you retrieve the variables from the config file, _(named `file.cfg` for the purposes of this comment)_, why don't you just get them using this: `@For /F UseBackTokens^=1-2Delims^=^" %%A In ("file.cfg")Do Set "%%A%%~B"`. This will save them already without their doublequotes!

Comment: …then again, as you're using `%~1`, `%~2`, `%~3` and `%~4` there's absolutely no need to remove the outer doublequotes anyhow! Additionally, I'm thinking that you could run just one `For` loop using `Set "line=!line:sign folder=%~1!"`, then `Set "line=!line:sign binary file=%~2!"` then `Set "line=!line:sign parameter=%~3!"` then `Echo !line!`.

Comment: Thanks RGuggisberg for your helpful thoughts. Yes Indeed, the version of that utility not the same between mine and my colleague. And his version is a later one and after installed on my PC, got the same issue which reproducible...

Comment: Thanks Compo for your useful input. I should try for that...

Comment: When youve updated/improved both scripts, if the issue remains unresolved, post your updated scripts into your question so that helpers are working with the same/correct information.

Comment: Compo, could you please help on this loop you mentioned For loop using Set "line=!line:sign folder=%~1!", then Set "line=!line:sign binary file=%~2!" then Set "line=!line:sign parameter=%~3!" then Echo !line!